# Is a separate SSL certificate required for primary and failover servers?

Tags: ssl, failover

I have a web application to be deployed in a windows 2003 server which is primary node. There is a failover node which is going to be added. The application requires SSL for its operations. I have two questions on getting an SSL certificate for the failover server.

I believe a separate SSL certificate is required for the website hosted in the failover server.

1. Am i right?
2. If the failover server is virtual, Does the above statement hold?

Thanks in advance 

Siva

Answer (score 5):

An SSL certificate is tied to the public domain name, not to an IP or internal domain name

If you have two servers:

- server1/192.168.1.1
- server2/192.168.1.2

That are serving a website:

https://yourwebsite.com

Ideally, if you have the failover/IIS/dns/network setup correctly, then you should be able to install the same cert on both servers.

Install the cert on the primary, then export the cert **with the private key** and install on the failover.

When the primary goes down, the failover will take over, with the same domain name and same certificate.

Rather than a failover, have you considered using load balancing? You get the same benifits of the failover, but get *maybe* double throughput